# Is it possible to correctly show imperial units with fractional grid lines?

Tags: transforms, units

I'm trying to display units in imperial inches/feet with 16ths of an inch. I know Ill have to enter fractional units in the editor but if the grid is setup I can at least snap to the fractions easily. I know Blender is not a cad program but I don't want to learn a separate program like fusion just for the few projects where I actually need cad-like designs.

I have units set to inches in the scene properties. I set the grid scale to 1/16 (.0625). It sort of works but the major grid lines show up every 12 tics rather than every 16. This makes easy to get confused. I understand that imperial isn't the most logical thing (12 inches in a foot, and inches are divided by 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc) but it's used enough I would hope there is some better option in blender. I think the crux of the issue is it would be illogical to have one level of zoom where it's split into 12 grid lines per foot, and you zoom in and get 16 grid lines per inch.

Does anyone have an settings that:

- makes it easier to use imperial while being able to use grid snap to fractions of an inch
- adds major tic lines every inch rather than every 12/16th of an inch.

In this image the grid line should be at the 16th tic not the 12th:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception on how *Units* and *Guides* work here. First of all, you have not set the units to *Inches* in your *Scene Properties*. You have set the *Length* to *Inches*, which is the how the values are shown in the item properties.

For example, here are the dimensions of a 1' × 2' plane *Length* set to *Feet* compared to *Inches*:

[image: unit vs. length]

When you set the *Unit System* to *Imperial* and leave the *Unit Scale* at 1, the units will always be *Feet*, even when you set the *Length* display to *Inches*.

And since the units are feet, it makes absolutely sense to have the grid lines at 12. This has nothing to do with your unnecessary rant "Why you hate America brah?", this is because 12" = 1', so I would rather say 1/12 is a "natural" subdivision of feet. Something similar when you have set the units to *Metric*, the subdivisions are always 10, if you like it or not.

The *Guides* > *Scale* now has not much to do with the units and subdivisions themselves. It is just how large or small the grid is in relation to the units. So a *Scale* of 2 in this case means, you do not want the main grid 1' × 1', but 2' × 2'. The subdivisions are scaled together with the main grid, so instead of having a grid line per 1", you now have a line every 2", keeping it at 12 subdivisions per 2 feet.

For the *Subdivisions*: you might not have noticed that, but they are greyed out. As I said, when using the *Unit Systems* either *Imperial* or *Metric*, the subdivisions are determined by that and are 12 or 10.

You can only use the *Subdivisions* option when you have set the *Units System* to *None*. In this case, Blender has no "natural" subdivision (yes, the default value is 10, but now you can change that and it will have an effect).

The only problem is, dimensions are not given in fractional numbers - so while you can now snap to 1/16th of the main grid, Blender will not show 1/16 but 0.0625 instead.

[image: no unit system]